# The entity related is always re-saved using oneToOne relationship

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, cascade

this is my entity reclamation it has a onetoone relation with user entity

[image]

and this my entity user :

[image]

in my database i have user created with id 1 .

i wont to save this json as mentionned :

```
  {   
        "title": "test2 user reclamartion",
        "description":"my test2 user description",
        "priorityEnum":"HIGH",
        "type":"OTHER",
        "publication" :{
            "id":"1"
        },
        "user":{
            "id":"1"
        }
 
  }
```

but it always create another user with another id in the database

Comment: don't post images of code, post the code itself

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to an existing entity, you will have to load that existing entity via `entityManager.find()` or get a reference via `entityManager.getReference()`.